# Get Goutte to work on shared host?

Tags: php, server, goutte

I installed Goutte on my local host using Composer. It works as expected when run using XAMPP. Then, I uploaded all the files from the vendor folder to server. Now, the script shows errors like:

> syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'in vendor/react/promise/src/functions.php on line 68

The file works perfectly without any modification on local host. What could be the possible reason?

Comment: We may need to see the code that creates this error in order to answer, (1) please add this in. What version of PHP are you running (2) locally, and (3) on your remote host? It might be that you need short array syntax, which requires PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

I have the save problem, upgrade my php version to 5.4.x solve my problem.
By the way, it's better to use Goutte.phar in production environment.